# How to repair a text file with line breaks in the middle of some lines?

Tags: php, csv, text

I have a text file and the problem is that there are some rows divided into two lines. Example:

```
Line 1 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5] 

Line 2 : value[1] , value[2] , 
Line 3 : value[3 *] , value[4 *] , value[5 *] 

Line 4 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5] 
Line 5 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5]
```

Now, how can I arrange these rows because I need to insert data into my database via PHP:

```
Line 1 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5] 

Line 2 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5] 


Line 3 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5] 
Line 4 : value[1] , value[2] , value[3] , value[4] , value[5]
```

Comment: How do you want to arrange them?

Comment: > Line 2 : value1 , value2 , value3 , value4 , value5 </b>

Comment: So what you are saying is, there is a unwanted new line in the middle of the string on line two making it stretch across two lines?

Comment: @Andreas exactly

Comment: The number of these files is 100 files, each file contains more than 500 lines

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Comment: Hi there. A number of women in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they feel a bit excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Comment: @halfer What? Who are you talking to and what is this gendered assumptions you talk about?

Comment: @Andreas: see [the edit I've made in rev #5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45500050/revisions). I was talking to the OP - perhaps I could have made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explode the string to an array and loop through the array. If there is not 4 commas it will combine two lines and unset the "previous".

```
$str = "value1 , value2 , value3 , value4 , value5
value1 , value2 ,
value3 , value4 , value5
value1 , value2 , value3 , value4 , value5
value1 , value2 , value3 , value4 , value5";

$arr= explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    if(substr_count($arr[$i], ",") != 4){
       $arr[$i+1] = $arr[$i] . " " . $arr[$i+1];
       unset($arr[$i]);
    }
}
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/EBQEX

Comment: I wonder whether the file in question is a CSV file? If so, the OP may wish to think about whether an entry of `"one, two"` (i.e. with quote marks) constitutes one entry or two. The [PHP CSV line reader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) can cope with that.

Comment: @halfer if that is the case then the question is poorly written. OP has not responded to my answer or even my question about my answer. If he/she (<- see, i didn't gender assume that Abdullah is a man ;-)  ) thinks it does not solve the problem he/she can just tell me and I will fix it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about chasing askers for an answer - some folks do not log in very often, and some folks will never log back on at all. It is the nature of online communities. I will sometimes downvote a question if the OP has gone on to ask new questions and ignored old answers, but otherwise there's not a lot you can do about it. Upvote for your efforts in the meantime (though I suggest you stick to lowercase for PHP keywords as the accepted standard).

Comment: Thanks but that is since I type most of my answers on my phone. And it auto capitalize first words of each sentence or line. I can force non capital letters but it's to much work since it most of the times work anyways.

Comment: I have noticed what you say about askers too.